# android get exception type

Tags: android, exception

I have an asynctask that's trying to send a mail in background. If the password or something else is not set up properly it throws exception. Depending of what exception it throws I need to show different text on toast. How can I get what exception was thrown so I can deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First catch the exception using `try catch` block.Then you can show toast on each `Exception` Block. You can catch specific `exceptions` and do according to your needs.

For e.g..:

```
    try{
          //your necessary codes
     } catch(Exception e)
          // show Toast 
     } catch(IOException e1) { 

     }catch (NullPointerException e2)

     }catch(RunTimeException e3) {

     }
```

etc.. like this...!!

Answer (score 2):

You can catch a exception from more specific to more generic.

```
                try {

            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                .....
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e( TAG , "Error" + ex.getMessage());
                                    Toast.maketext(.......)
            }
```

You can take a look at exceptions here: http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-exception/index.shtml
You can pick up one or define your own.

Comment: Also you can make your own exception control using exception message.

Comment: ex.getMessage() can return null, and then whole application is crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Please place the below code to show the `Toast` message whenever u caught an `Exception`:

```
  try{
  // Place the code which you think, will get an Exception
  } catch(Exception e) { 
   // show Toast as below:
    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```